# How to make Picklist values Required in VF page required = true is not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist

VF Page

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Start_Date__c}" />
           <apex:selectList value="{!Opportunity.Customer_Group_ERP__c}" id="customer" size="1" multiselect="false" required="true">
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>   
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="SAMSUNG" itemLabel="SAMSUNG"/>    
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="SAE MAGNETICS" itemLabel="SAE MAGNETICS"/>    
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="MICRON GROUP" itemLabel="MICRON GROUP"/>    
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="TOSHIBA" itemLabel="TOSHIBA"/>    
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="TSMC" itemLabel="TSMC"/>    
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="INTEL" itemLabel="INTEL"/>     
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="GLOBALFOUNDRIES" itemLabel="GLOBALFOUNDRIES"/>    
                   <apex:selectOption itemValue="NANYA" itemLabel="NANYA"/> 
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="POWERCHIP" itemLabel="POWERCHIP"/>    
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="WINBOND" itemLabel="WINBOND"/>    
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="UMC" itemLabel="UMC"/>   
                  <apex:selectOption itemValue="Others" itemLabel="Others"/>  
                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="C"/>

                  </apex:selectList> 

          <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.CloseDate}"/>



           <apex:selectList value="{!Opportunity.PM_I_Business_Field__c}" size="1" style="width:400px" >
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!TypeOptions}"/>                  

                            </apex:selectList> 

            <apex:selectList value="{!Opportunity.Node_Size__c}" size="1" multiselect="false" id="D">
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!Node}" />                  
                   </apex:selectList>
```

Controller

```
public class CreateOppExtension 
{

    Opportunity opp {get;set;}
    String Owner {get;set;}

      ApexPages.StandardController GstdController;
     public CreateOppExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
     {   
        GstdController= stdController;
        opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
        opp.Notes__c = 'Testing';


    }
           public List<SelectOption> getTypeOptions()
       {


           List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
           options.add(new SelectOption('None','--None--'));
           Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Opportunity.PM_I_Business_Field__c.getDescribe();
           List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
           for(Schema.PicklistEntry p : ple)
               options.add(new SelectOption(p.getLabel(), p.getValue())); 
           return options;


       }
    public List<SelectOption> getNode()
       {


           List<SelectOption> reason = new List<SelectOption>();
           reason.add(new SelectOption('None','--None--'));
           Schema.DescribeFieldResult Rea = Opportunity.Reason_PM_I__c.getDescribe();
           List<Schema.PicklistEntry> R = Rea.getPicklistValues();
           for(Schema.PicklistEntry Q : R)
               reason.add(new SelectOption(Q.getLabel(), Q.getValue())); 
           return reason;


       }
```

Comment: Why don't you convert the field `Customer_Group_ERP__c` to picklist on the Opportunity object and make it required. Then using `apex:inputField` will do the trick for you.

Comment: @Kevan there are different record types on Opportunites which does not want the field as required..There are other picklist fields which needs to be required :(

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
<apex:selectOption itemValue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>
```

Just remove the `itemValue` parameter, or set it to null/empty.

```
<apex:selectOption itemValue="" itemLabel="--None--"/>
```

Setting `required="true"` as a `<apex:selectList>` parameter should throw an error then.

For example, using the below code:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
    <apex:pageMessages id="errors" />
    <apex:form>
        <apex:selectList id="customer" size="1" multiselect="false" required="true">
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="" itemLabel="--None--"/>   
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="SAMSUNG" itemLabel="SAMSUNG"/>    
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="SAE MAGNETICS" itemLabel="SAE MAGNETICS"/>    
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="MICRON GROUP" itemLabel="MICRON GROUP"/>    
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="TOSHIBA" itemLabel="TOSHIBA"/>    
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="TSMC" itemLabel="TSMC"/>    
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="INTEL" itemLabel="INTEL"/>     
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="GLOBALFOUNDRIES" itemLabel="GLOBALFOUNDRIES"/>    
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="NANYA" itemLabel="NANYA"/> 
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="POWERCHIP" itemLabel="POWERCHIP"/>    
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="WINBOND" itemLabel="WINBOND"/>    
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="UMC" itemLabel="UMC"/>   
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Others" itemLabel="Others"/>  
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="C"/>
        </apex:selectList> 
        <apex:commandButton value="Submit" reRender="errors" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Throws the following:

[image]